# Can using GfxCardStatus, v2.3 strictly on Integrated only cause damage to a MBP?

Tags: macbook-pro

Surprise, surprise the graphics card on my mid-2010 MBP failed or was corrupted. Seems there is a definite trend with these MB's and their graphics cards failing. Anywho, Found out it was out-of-warranty and took it to the geniuses who quoted me at 310$ to have the motherboard et cetera repaired. I opted out and read that I could simply use GfxCardStatus, v2.3 on Integrated graphics only. Since using it, I haven't had any intermittent shutdowns or the others issues associated with such. However, this seems to good to by true. What is the caveat to using this software? will it eventually ruin my computer or cause any adverse side-effects?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It just prevents the computer from switching to other graphics card. There should be nothing to worry about. Although, when I was using it on my 2012, there were some rare scenarios where it didn't "catch it" and it switched anyway, which of course caused the freeze.

Comment: That's a relief! Thank you for taking the time to write this!